# I'm reusing sorted array, but I want to use the new generated array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

In this code, I'm reusing sorted array again and again and that's why the output from the 2nd time is very low compared to the first one. Can anybody help please?

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UseSorts {

public static int[] makeArray(int x) {

    int[] a = new int[x];
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    Random r = new Random(1234);
    a[i] = r.nextInt();
    }
    return a;
}

public static void InsertionSort(int[] x) {

    long start = System.nanoTime();
    Sorts.InsertionSort(x);
    long finish = System.nanoTime();
    long total = finish - start;
    System.out.println("elapsed time is: " + total);


} 
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the number of elements: ");
    int number = in.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        int[] arr = makeArray(number);
        InsertionSort(arr);

    }

} 

}
```

```
Enter the number of elements: 100
elapsed time is: 1930646
elapsed time is: 7926
elapsed time is: 7692
elapsed time is: 7590
elapsed time is: 7555
elapsed time is: 7649
elapsed time is: 7560
elapsed time is: 7592
elapsed time is: 7685
elapsed time is: 12281
```

Comment: What do you want? Create new array before calling the sorting method? Or pass a `clone()` of it each time (obviously before sorting)?

Comment: @Gabor - How is he reusing the array? He is allocating memory inside the loop. I don't see your point.

Comment: You are not reusing the array. Do

int[] arr = makeArray(number);
System.out.println(arr.toString());

Run this and you'll see different references. If you were reusing the array elements, you'd see the same reference in the loop

Comment: @FarhanSyed Sorry, I missed that.

Comment: I see a recursive call which does not have a breaking logic. Shouldnt this be throwing a stackoverflow exception?

Answer (score 0):

Except the first run, all other runs are consistent. You might have to consider the Eclipse overhead or the overhead of the tool you are using to reason the first run time. I am not sure what's the exact reason, but, I can tell you that you are not re-using the memory, all other class variables look fine. If you ignore the first run, all other runs are very consistent.